# Cypress: Error: Webpack Compilation Error Module not found

Tags: windows, cypress

Windows 10.
Cypress установлен с помощью Node по букварю в папку проекта.
При попытке запустить тестовый скрипт, падает ошибка (детали на скриншоте)

```
  it('passes', () => {
    cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io')
  })
})


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGcV3.png
```